# Labeled grouping by geometry in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling

I have a layer of lines that represent stretches of electrical conductors. These sections have a point of origin and an end point. One of its attributes is the length of each of the sections.

Some of these sections have the same point of origin and the same ending point, so when I label these lines by their length, this repeated data appears for each of the lines and the data is repeated.

I need that when labeling the layer, only the label of one of the lines appears, that is, that the distance between each of the points is represented. I have tried to do it by means of a labeling based on rules, and some function of aggregation by geometry, so that only one label is shown for each space between points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another approach:

If your have an unique numeric field, such as `id` = *1, 2, ...*, you can call it in the expression to distinguish one of overlapping lines.

In the `Label with` window, give expression:

```
CASE WHEN "id" = minimum("id" , group_by:=geom_to_wkt($geometry)) THEN "length"
ELSE NULL
END
```

which would look like below.

[image]

This example picks up minimum `id` field, but you can use any numeric field.
(`"length"` is the field which stores the length attribute).

Comment: Thanks Kazuhito! It's the perfect solution for me. Thanks very much!

Comment: I"m glad. Thank you @EmilioAbad :D

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to create a new layer just for your labels.

1. In the QGIS Processing Toolbox, go to `QGIS geoalgorithms | Vector general tools | Delete duplicate geometries`. This create a new layer `"Cleaned"` without duplicated lines.
2. Set layer properties of `"Cleaned"` to show the labels only. (so the  style has to be `No symbols` instead of `Single symbol`)
3. Remove label from your original layer.

Comment: Thanks Kazuhito, thanks for your answer, but I'm looking for an option without creating a new layer
regards

Comment: @EmilioAbad Got that, thanks for your response. Please see another post which does not need to create a new layer, but requires a field you can use to distinguish one of those overlapping lines.